# Unable to add Fileoutline (PDF Bookmarks) to my resume template

Tags: overleaf, resume, awesome-cv

I am new to LaTeX and this community.
I am using Overleaf Template for my resume: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm

I have made several changes to fonts, color, etc.

Currently stuck at:

- Adding bookmarks to generated PDF. It uses a custom \section syntax and I am unable to use \pdfbookmark as it's not getting recognized.
- Failed in making it ATS compatible by adding unicode: \pdfgentounicode=1
- In the \cventry section, the letter 'i' is getting converted to lowercase when copying the content to notepad.
  Example: `\cventry {\textbf{Master of Science in Computer Science}} % Degree {XYZ University} % Institution`

Copied text: MASTER OF SCiENCE iN COMPUTER SCiENCE // XYZ University

Also, if you guys have any recommendations for ATS-friendly resume template, I'll be more than happy to use them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will not debug an external template, you will have to add a small complete example here. Load hyperref for the bookmarks. There is no need for pdfgentounicode, a current latex activates that by default.